# Плавная прокрутка к якорю jQuery

Tags: jquery, меню, прокрутка

Здравствуйте, я пока только учусь...немного не догоняю, в общем на странице есть меню

```
<ul>
<li><a class="link active" href=/home>Главная</a></li>
<li><a class="link" href=/service>Услуги</a></li>
<li><a class="link" href=/reserv>Бронь</a></li>
</ul>
```

При прокрутке колесиком или ползунком вниз по сайту URL принимает вид мойсайт/#/home т.е. есть разделение мойсайт+/#/+соответствующий раздел сайта (div ID) с помощью функции attr('href'). Именно такое разделение принципиально важно. Теперь нужно просто сделать плавную прокрутку к якорю (div ID) или Name в общем чтобы к нужному разделу прокручивалось и URL при этом соответственно менялся. Буду рад любым советам, подсказкам и указаниям. Спасибо

Comment: плагин scrollTo

Answer (score 2):

Для плавного скролл использую обычно вот эту маленькую функцию, просто вставь её в код и всё.

```
/*! Smooth Scrolling http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/ */
$(function(){$("a[href*=#]:not([href=#])").click(function(){if(location.pathname.replace(/^\//,"")==this.pathname.replace(/^\//,"")&&location.hostname==this.hostname){var t=$(this.hash);if(t=t.length?t:$("[name="+this.hash.slice(1)+"]"),t.length)return $("html,body").animate({scrollTop:t.offset().top},1000),!1}})});
```

Answer (score 0):

Небольшая функция на `Vanilla JS`:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/277s9ef3/5/)

```
/**
* scrollTo прокручивает страницу до указанного в ней места
* @param {HTMLElement} to   элемент до которого прокручиваем
* @param {Number}      time время анимации в мс
*/
function scrollTo(to, time) {
    var from = window.pageYOffset;
    var to = to.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var speed = time / (to - from);
    var start = null;

    requestAnimationFrame(step);
    function step(timestamp) {
        if (start === null) start = timestamp;
        var progress = timestamp - start;
        var y = (to < 0 ? Math.max(from - progress/speed, current + to) : Math.min(from + progress/speed, from + to));
        window.scrollTo(0,y);
        if (y < from + to) {
            requestAnimationFrame(step)
        }
    }
}
```